# Cut between 360 degree and 2D video?

Tags: youtube, virtual-reality, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality

Does anyone know if it's possible to cut between 360 degree footage and regular 2D footage in a single YouTube video? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this question is related to computer programming.

As far as I know, Youtube as a platform doesn't allow this kind of transition as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of transition is not possible, but you could render normal footage as part of a 360 stream as a kind of a rendered video screen floating in space.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use an Android app called DU Recorder to capture your phone display, then play the 360 video on your phone and point it to wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, youtube needs the 360 video metadata to recognize 360 video. So you cannot play it on 360 and then on 2d. With the metadata it will play 360 always. This 360 video editor 360 vr video editor from http://molanisvr.com has a 2d video on 360 video so you can insert the 2d video into the 360 video